# Show count of seasons from table "episodes" can't format the query

Tags: mysql, format

Hello guys well I have a site where have anime episodes in a table episodes that table stores the normal info of an episose and a column season and that is the question: I wanna format a query to show how much seasons exist searching in the episodes posted where `id = $serieid` and `season = $season` >> but my brain is blocked really I don't know a lot `MySQL`:

```
SELECT Count(*)[??Seasons] FROM episodes WHERE id = $serie_id;
```

I really get confused I have little experience in `MySQL`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remember that database questions are highly situational so you'll need to give us an idea of the schema involved. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` can help with that. Please add any schema code to the question with an edit, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new table named "tAnime" in order to give you a full working code. Assuming that you have all the chapters for each season stored in the table,  if you want to know how many seasons there are you just have to check for the maximum value in the column "season".

```
/* Database table creation */
CREATE TABLE tAnime(id integer PRIMARY KEY, title text, chapter integer, season integer);

/* Inserting some values */     
INSERT INTO tAnime values(1, 'My Name is Konohamaru!', 2, 1);
INSERT INTO tAnime values(2, 'The Oath of Pain', 8, 1);
INSERT INTO tAnime values(3, 'The Forest of Chakra', 10, 1);
INSERT INTO tAnime values(4, 'Clone vs. Clone: Mine are Better than Yours!', 36, 2);
INSERT INTO tAnime values(5, 'A Failure Stands Tall!', 47, 2);

/* Selecting the number of seasons the anime has */
SELECT MAX(season) AS numberOfSeasons FROM tAnime;
```

That will do.

Comment: Thanks so much @Lebenswasser